# How to push data from local SQL Server to Tableau Server on AWS

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tableau-api

We are developing Tableau dashboards and deploying the workbooks on a EC2 windows instance in AWS. One of the data source is the company SQL server inside firewall. The server is managed by IT and we only have read permission to one of the databases. Now the solution is to build workbook on Tableau desktop locally by connecting to the company SQL server. Before publishing the workbooks to Tableau server, the data are extracted from data sources. The static data got uploaded with workbooks when published.

Instead of linking to static extracted data on Tableau server, we would like to set up a database on AWS (e.g. Postgresql), probably on the same instance and push the data from company SQL server to AWS database.

There may be a way to push directly from SQL server to postgres on AWS. But since we don't have much control of the server plus the IT folks are probably not willing to push data to external, this will not be an option. What I can think of is as follows:

1. Set up Postgres on AWS instance and create the tables with same schemas as the ones in SQL server.
2. Extract data from SQL server and save as CSV files. One table per file.
3. Enable file system sharing on AWS windows instance. So the instance can read files from local file system directly.
4. Load data from CSV to Postgres tables.
5. Set up the data connection on Tableau Server on AWS to read data from Postgres.

I don't know if others have come across a situation like this and what their solutions are. But I think this is not a uncommon scenario. One change would be to have both local Tableau Desktop and AWS Tableau Server connect to Postgres on AWS. Not sure if local Tableau could access Postgres on AWS though.

We also want to automate the whole process as much as possible. On local server, I can probably run a Python script as cron job to frequently export data from SQL server and save to CSVs. On the server side, something similar will be run to load data from CSV to Postgres. If the files are big, though, it may be pretty slow to import data from CSV to postgres. But there is no better way to transfer files from local to AWS EC2 instance programmatically since it is Windows instance.

I am open to any suggestions.

Comment: First suggestion: if your source database is SQL Sever, _don't_ make the replicated database a completely different platform! Make it SQL Server! Depending on the data volume, SQL Express is free. Just be aware that you are building 'shadow IT' here. Although IT may appear to be unhelpful and unwieldy, there are good reasons for the things they do.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by your last statement: _But there is no better way to transfer files from local to AWS EC2 instance programmatically since it is Windows instance_. There are many was to push data from a local SQL instance to a SQL cloud instance. Pushing data from local means you don't have to open any firewalls to the outside world (an IT exercise) so this is your best bet. You can for example run a scheduled windows job that extracts data to native BCP format then pushes it up to the cloud (again using BCP) (this is just a batch file)

Comment: Here's an example of transferring data from one SQL Server to another using BCP: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/step-by-step-how-to-move-sql-server-data-efficiently-with-the-bulk-copy-program/ . Remember: if you push from local, you don't have to open any firewalls. If you want to write something in the cloud to pull data, you need to open an incoming port for your local SQL Server (something IT will never do)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid From the BCP link, it seems like this tool comes with MS SQL server. However I cannot login to the server to run this command. We were only provided with a database connection. I view data on my machine with Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I meant if the EC2 instance is Linux, you can use scp command to push files. Do you have any suggestions for how to upload file from local to a Windows AWS instance?

Comment: Whatever connection you use to connect using SSMS, you can use in BCP. So is Linux / Postgres a reqiurement here or not? As I mentioned, replicating from SQL Server to postgres will be difficult. Replicating from SQL Server to SQL Server will be straightforward. Note that SQL Server now runs on Linux. I really need to know your true constraints here.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid There are three machines, source SQL server A, my workstation B, and destination server C. You are suggesting to run BCP on B to output data from A to a file on B and then run BCP again on B to input the file to database on C? I need to install SQL server on B to run BCP and connect to database on A, right? It does not have to be Linux/Postgres, just my personal preference. If it is easier to use BCP with SQL server on both end, I will definitely give it a shot. One concern is that setting up a Amazon RDS instance with SQL server is more expensive than postgres and mysql

Comment: Yes that's a correct summary of what I'm suggesting. I think this is a good point to document in an answer

Comment: Can the AWS instance connect to the SQL Server source? In that case an a foreign data wrapper to SQL Server could be used and materialized views to cache the data locally in Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A. Platform choice**

If you use a database other than SQL Server on AWS (say Postgres), you need to perform one (or maybe two) conversions:

1. In the integration from on on-prem SQl Server to AWS database you need to map from SQL Server datatypes to postgres datatypes
2. I don't know much about Tableau, but if it is currently pointing at SQL Server, you probably need some kind of conversion to point it at Postgres

These two steps alone might make it worth your while to investigate a SQL Express RDS. SQL Express has no licencing cost but obviously windows does. You can also run SQL Express on Linux which would have no licencing costs, but would require a lot of fiddling about to get running (i.e. I doubt if there is a SQL Express Linux RDS available)

**B. Integration Approach**

- Any process external to your network (i.e. on the cloud) that is pulling data from your network will need the firewall opened. Assuming this is not an option, that leaves us only with push from on-prem options
- Just as an aside on this point, Power BI achieves it's desktop data integration by using a desktop 'gateway' that coordinates data transfer, meaning that cloud Power BI doesn't need to open a port to get what it needs, it uses the desktop gateway to push it out
- Given that we only have push options, then we need something on-prem to push data out. Yes, this could be a cron job on Linux or a windows scheduled task. Please note, this is where you start creating shadow IT
- To get data out of SQL Server to be pushed to the cloud, the easiest way is to use BCP.EXE to generate flat files. If these are going into a SQL Server, these should be native format (to save complexity). If these are going to Postgres they should be tab delimited
- If these files are being uploaded to SQL Server, then it's just another BCP command to push native files into tables into SQL Server (prior to this you need to run SQLCMD.EXE command to truncate the target table

So for three tables, assuming you'd installed the free* SQL Server client tools, you'd have a batch file something like this:

```
REM STEP 1:  Clear staging folder
DEL /Y C:\Staging\*.TXT

REM STEP 2: Generate the export files
BCP database.dbo.Table1 OUT C:\Staging\Table1.TXT -E -S LocalSQLServer -N
BCP database.dbo.Table2 OUT C:\Staging\Table2.TXT -E -S LocalSQLServer -N
BCP database.dbo.Table3 OUT C:\Staging\Table3.TXT -E -S LocalSQLServer -N


REM STEP 3: Clear target tables
REM Your SQL RDS is unlikely to support single sign on 
REM so need to use user/pass here
SQLCMD -U username -P password -S RDSSQLServerName -d databasename -Q"TRUNCATE TABLE Table1; TRUNCATE TABLE Table2; TRUNCATE TABLE Table3;"

REM STEP 4: Push data in
BCP database.dbo.Table1 IN C:\Staging\Table1.TXT -U username -P password -S RDSSQLServerName-N
BCP database.dbo.Table2 IN C:\Staging\Table2.TXT -U username -P password -S RDSSQLServerName-N
BCP database.dbo.Table3 IN C:\Staging\Table3.TXT -U username -P password -S RDSSQLServerName-N
```

(I'm *pretty* sure that BCP and SQLCMD are free... not sure but you can certainly download the free SQL Server tools and see)

If you wanted to push to Postgres SQL instead,

- in step 2, you'd need to drop the -N option, which would make the file text, tab delimited, readable by anything
- in step 3 and step 4 you'd need to use the associated Postgres command line tool, but you'd need to deal with data types etc. (which can be a pain - ambiguous date formats alone are always a huge problem)

Also note here the AWS RDS instance is just another database with a hostname, login, password. The only thing you have to do is make sure the firewall is open on the AWS side to accept incoming connections from your IP Address

There are many more layers of sophistication you can build into your integration: differential replication, retries etc. but given the 'shadow IT status' this might not be worth it

Also be aware that I think AWS charges for data uploads, so if you are replicating a 1G database everyday, that's going to add up. (Azure doesn't charge for uploads but I'm sure you'll pay in some other way!)

Comment: Instead of db replication, is it possible to do incremental loading in this scenario? That is retrieving only the new records from the source db and load them to target db in AWS.

Comment: You need to know what the new records are. So you need an incrementing key or date stamp in the source.

Answer (score 1):

For this type of problem I would strongly recommend use of SymmetricDS - https://www.symmetricds.org/

The main caveat is that the SQL Server would require the addition of some triggers to track changes but at that point SymmetricDS will handle the push of the data.

An alternative approach, similar to what you suggested, would be to have a script export the data into CSV files, upload them to S3, and then have a bucket event trigger on the S3 bucket that kicks off a Lambda to load the data when it arrives.